# Extract multicolumn(?) PDFs in python

Tags: python, pdf, ocr, pdfbox, text-mining

I'm trying to write a program to convert multi-page PDFs to plain text in bulk (think many page textbooks). If I run it through `PyPDF2`, I find issues where if a particular page has 2 columns, it reads incorrectly.

The best solution I have found is the use [OCRmyPDF](https://github.com/ocrmypdf/OCRmyPDF) to convert scanned PDFs to text PDFs, and use `tabulizer::extract_text()` in R (via a [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69211650/13112739), which is a R wrapper of [tabula PDF](https://github.com/tabulapdf/tabula), which has a python wrapper, but this function is based on [Apache PDFBox](https://pdfbox.apache.org/), which does not have a [current python wrapper](https://github.com/lebedov/python-pdfbox/tree/master#notes)). The only python solution I can find is to run `tesseract` with both 1 and 2 column options and select the one with more semantic information, but this is incredibly slow.

Answer (score 0):

In general, extracting text from multi-column PDF is a challenging task. If you want to extract plain text, you might want to use the `pdftohml` command under linux: https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/pdftohtml.1.html

It makes a decent job at extracting multi-column text.

There exist ports of  this utility for Windows.

If you are satisfied with the result, you can automate the execution of the shell command from python.

Comment: For decently built PDFs, this script using PyMuPDF also aims to solve this task: https://github.com/pymupdf/PyMuPDF-Utilities/blob/master/text-extraction/multi_column.py.